# Since when, and why, are all Question titles in the mobile view overview ORANGE?

Tags: discussion, bug

Did I do something wrong, does it mean anything or is this corporate design gone terribly wrong?

And most importantly, how can I turn it off, please?

Comment: [It was a network-wide bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367641/379643), which has [now been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367643/379643). Everything should be back to the usual colors now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's solved